# android todo list application question

Tags: android

i am a newbie trying to learn android by doing a todo application.
so far i have:

- list all todos
- create a todo(insert into database)

i need help adding a delete feature
my xml structure for todo list is that i have a TableLayout. and to display my todo list, i put my todo in a textview and i put that textview into a tablerow and i put that tablerow into my tablelayout.

now i want to add a delete button to the right of my todo list. my question is
**is there a default delete button that i can use? 
how do i handle the onclick event, i mean like if a click on a delete button, how do i know which todo this button is for?
and is my layout correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a TableLayout is probably not the right way to do this. If you use a ListView, it can automatically handle adding rows when more information is added to the database, refreshing the list when information is changed, and accepting user clicks. However, a ListView is a bit more complicated to use since you have to use a ListAdapter. To be honest I've never tried creating a List directly out of an SQL database, but it's probably doable. I suggest you look for tutorials in ListViews (the ApiDemos example app Google distributes is a good place to see a few lists in action), and then look for examples binding a database to the list.

Answer (score 2):

[Common Tasks and How to Do Them in Android](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html)